# Access SQL Multiple Unions with Group BY

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, inner-join, union-all

I'm trying to run this query:

```
SELECT
    HH.`Household id` AS HH_HH_ID,
    HH.`Annualized Premium Amount` AS HH_Annualized_Premium,
    GQ.`Referal SRC Id` AS GQ_Source_ID,
    count(*) AS Total_HH
FROM
    Households HH 
INNER JOIN
    GatewayQ GQ
ON
    GQ.`Household Id` = HH.`Household id`
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    HH.`Household id` AS HH_HH_ID, 
    HH.`Annualized Premium Amount` AS HH_Annualized_Premium, 
    GQ.`Referal SRC Id` AS GQ_Source_ID,
    count(*) AS Total_HH 
FROM 
    Households HH 
INNER JOIN 
    GatewayQ GQ 
ON 
    GQ.`Email`= HH.`Email`
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    HH.`Household id` AS HH_HH_ID, 
    HH.`Annualized Premium Amount` AS HH_Annualized_Premium, 
    GQ.`Referal SRC Id` AS GQ_Source_ID,
    count(*) AS Total_HH
FROM 
    Households HH 
INNER JOIN 
    GatewayQ GQ 
    ON GQ.`Zip`= HH.`Zip` AND
    GQ.`Last Name`= HH.`Last Name` AND
    GQ.`First Name`= HH.`First Name`
GROUP BY 
    GQ_Source_ID
HAVING 
    GQ_Source_ID LIKE 'ps%'
ORDER BY 
    GQ.`Referal SRC Id`, HH_Annualized_Premium ASC;
```

When I try to run in Access, I get a message that my ORDER BY expressions includes fields that are not selected by the query.  I don't understand why I'm getting this, when I'm clearly selecting all the cols in all 3 selects...

What I'm trying to get to, is to get a sum on premium and a count of unique households (as defined by the household id), from all 3 tables, the first one matching on household ID, the second one on e-mail address, and the final one on a combination of last name and zip code.  If there's a duplicate after the 3 different matches, I want the source id that begins with "ps" to get credit, and add the premium to a running total of all premiums and the household to increment by one, and disregard the rest of the duplicates.  If GQ_Source_ID does not contain ps, it could be one of 6 other values, I DO care what those values are, but there are about 300 "flavors" of ps, I don't want to know each one, just that it's one that starts with ps.

Example Table:

```
HHID    |HHPremium     |REfSrc
1       |100.00        |g1
1       |150.00        |ps1
2       |125.00        |r1
1       |100.00        |ps167
4       |100.00        |y1
4       |160.00        |g1
3       |100.00        |r1
4       |100.00        |y1
9       |140.00        |ps61
2       |100.00        |g1
7       |150.00        |ps1
4       |170.00        |r1
```

Desired Output:

```
HHID    |HHPremium     |REfSrc     |HHCount
1       |360.00        |g1         |3
1       |440.00        |ps*        |3
2       |395.00        |r1         |3
4       |100.00        |y1         |1
```

Logic:

--(Since g1 RefSrc matches, and HHIDs are unique, rows 1, 6 and 10 are grouped, their premium is added to the total, and HH count is incremented by 1 per row).

--(Since ps% RefSrc in row 2, 4, 9 and 11 match, but HHIDs are not unique in rows 2 & 4, row 4 is dropped and not tallied, we just tally and sum rows 2, 9, and 11).

--(Since r1 RefSrc in row 3, 7, and 12 match, and HHIDs are unique, HHCount is incremented and HHPremium is Summed to the total).

--(Finally, REfSrc y1 in rows 5 and 8 has a duplicate HHID so we count the first instance and eliminate the second).

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `ORDER BY 
    GQ.`Referal SRC Id`, HH_Annualized_Premium ASC;` should be `ORDER BY 
    GQ_Source_ID, HH_Annualized_Premium ASC;` and I think you're having applies to all the queries or just the last one?

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING and ORDER BY should apply to the output of the 3 selects collectively.

Comment: Modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Forgive me if I misspoke. If GQ_Source_ID does not contain ps, it could be one of 6 other values, I DO care what those values are, but there are about 300 "flavors" of ps, I don't want to know each one, just that it's one that starts with ps.

Comment: Post SPECIFICALLY what the data looks like in the Households table AND the GatewayQ table. Why are you trying to join the same table three different ways? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: GatewayQ is a quote database, and Households is a client database.  Trying to match up the quote source from the quote db to see where our current clients came from to fill out a quote.  I'm joining the same table multiple times, because I'm trying to match the different ways the data could line up between the tables, because sometimes we'll get different e-mail addresses, addresses and phone numbers from clients from what they provided in the quote process.

Comment: In your example table, you have row 2 and 4 HHID = 1 and RefSRC = PS1, PS167. The income is different though, so they are distinct records. What criteria do you use to determine which one you keep and which one you ignore?

Comment: Also, if your quotes table includes a HHID, why not join solely on the Households.HHID field?

Comment: @SandPiper great questions.  The quote could be different because they could be different quotes for different products.  Generally there isn't a huge difference in the amount, we're just looking for directionality from this report, we have another full report that would capture the actual amount sold to a household.  We don't join solely on HHID because only about 30% of our client's HHs are fed back into the quote system (if you're a previous household, we'll pull it for future quotes, but if you're a new prospect, you haven't been assigned an HHID till you actually purchase).

Comment: So going forward though, you still didn't answer this question: What criteria do you use to determine which one you keep and which one you ignore if there are multiple PS entries with different premiums?

Comment: @SandPiper In the past, we've just kept the first instance, going forward, it would produce a more accurate result to keep the larger premium amount.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Each select in the union is independent of the others.   The a group by needs to be applied to each query for the 3 non-aggregate fields.

I moved the having to an outside query since it applies to the results of the union and use the union-ed tables as an inline view; and then change the having to a where clause on the outer select..

I didn't think ms-access used back ticks to denote column names so brackets `[]` instead. and I corrected your order by from `GQ.Referal SRC Id`, to `GQ_Source_ID` since it is now referencing the inline view.

```
SELECT Z.* 
FROM (SELECT HH.[Household id] AS HH_HH_ID,
             HH.[Annualized Premium Amount] AS HH_Annualized_Premium,
             GQ.[Referal SRC Id] AS GQ_Source_ID,
             count(*) AS Total_HH
      FROM Households HH 
      INNER JOIN GatewayQ GQ
       ON GQ.[Household Id] = HH.[Household id]
      GROUP BY HH.[Household id]
             , HH.[Annualized Premium Amount]
             , GQ.[Referal SRC Id]
      UNION ALL
      SELECT HH.[Household id] AS HH_HH_ID, 
             HH.[Annualized Premium Amount] AS HH_Annualized_Premium, 
             GQ.[Referal SRC Id] AS GQ_Source_ID,
             count(*) AS Total_HH 
      FROM  Households HH 
      INNER JOIN GatewayQ GQ 
        ON GQ.Email= HH.Email
      GROUP BY HH.[Household id]
             , HH.[Annualized Premium Amount]
             , GQ.[Referal SRC Id]
      UNION ALL
      SELECT HH.[Household id] AS HH_HH_ID, 
             HH.[Annualized Premium Amount] AS HH_Annualized_Premium, 
             GQ.[Referal SRC Id] AS GQ_Source_ID,
             count(*) AS Total_HH
      FROM Households HH 
      INNER JOIN GatewayQ GQ 
        ON GQ.Zip= HH.Zip
       AND GQ.[Last Name]= HH.[Last Name]
       AND GQ.[First Name]= HH.[First Name]
      GROUP BY HH.[Household id]
             , HH.[Annualized Premium Amount]
             , GQ.[Referal SRC Id]) Z
WHERE Z.GQ_Source_ID LIKE 'ps%'
ORDER BY Z.GQ_Source_ID
       , Z.HH_Annualized_Premium ASC;
```

Comment: Updated to replace backticks with [] for MSAccess and refactored to eliminate scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Access uses brackets to specify columns with special characters in the name. This complication is just one reason why you should use underscores instead of spaces while naming them.

The GROUP BY clause is applied to each individual query before the union. You also did not adequately specify all fields that needed to be aggregated when using COUNT(*), so I added the additional fields into the statement.

Moving all of it into a subquery in the FROM clause will allow you to use the alias name in the ORDER BY clause.

Finally, you can only provide field aliases to the first SELECT statement in the union group. Trying to re-alias something after the UNION will give you an error. The corrected code should at least get you a working query.

**UPDATE:** Ok, so based on your feedback here's what I'm doing. First, I cleaned up your query and removed the `count(*)` from your UNIONed queries. Then, I selected only the unique fields from that by finding the maximum premium. That eliminates your duplicates in the ps* category.

Finally, I used all of that as a sub table that I selected from with the SUM function on the premiums:

```
SELECT HH_HH_ID, SUM(HH_Annualized_Premium) AS HH_Premium, GQ_Source_ID
FROM
  (SELECT HH_HH_ID, MAX(HH_Annualized_Premium), GQ_Source_ID FROM
  (SELECT
      HH.[Household id] AS HH_HH_ID,
      HH.[Annualized Premium Amount] AS HH_Annualized_Premium,
      GQ.[Referal SRC Id] AS GQ_Source_ID
  FROM Households HH INNER JOIN GatewayQ GQ ON GQ.[Household Id] = HH.[Household id]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
      HH.[Household id], 
      HH.[Annualized Premium Amount],
      GQ.[Referal SRC Id]
  FROM Households HH INNER JOIN GatewayQ GQ ON GQ.[Email]= HH.[Email]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
      HH.[Household id],
      HH.[Annualized Premium Amount],
      "ps*"
  FROM Households HH INNER JOIN GatewayQ GQ ON 
      GQ.[Zip]= HH.[Zip] AND
      GQ.[Last Name]= HH.[Last Name] AND
      GQ.[First Name]= HH.[First Name]
  WHERE GQ_Source_ID LIKE 'ps%')
  GROUP BY HH_HH_ID, GQ_Source_ID) temp_table
GROUP BY HH_HH_ID, GQ_Source_ID
ORDER BY 
    GQ_Source_ID, HH_Annualized_Premium;
```

Of note, I do not have the HHCount field in here. I don't think that is what you are after. Looking at your problem statement, that count is actually a tally of how many referrals were in each type (g1, r1, y1, ps*, etc.). Those tallies do not really mean anything specific to the household ID in the recordset, and therefore do not really belong in this query.